# Select identical entries (LIKE)

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-like

```
SELECT F.* FROM FlightSchedule F, Aircrafts A 
WHERE F.aircraftType = A.aircraftType 
LIKE CONCAT('\"','%', F.aircraftType, '%','\"') AND F.flightNum_arr='3913';
```

**SAMPLE CONTENT OF DB TABLES:**

Table "Schedule"

```
aircraftType = "320"
```

Table "Aircrafts"

```
aircraftType = "A320"
aircraftType = "A330"
```

The expected result of the query is the selection of an entry that has `aircraftType = "320"` and `flightNum_arr = "3913"`, because `"320"` is identical to `"A320"`. The problem is that `"320"` and `"A320"` are not considered as identical in this query. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `=` for exact match, or `LIKE` for pattern match, but don't put both of them into the same expression. And you don't need to concat quotes into the `LIKE` pattern.

```
SELECT F.*
FROM FlightSchedule F
JOIN Aircrafts A
ON A.aircraftType LIKE CONCAT('%', F.aircraftType, '%')
WHERE F.flightNum_arr = '3913'
```

Comment: It says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'F JOIN Aircrafts A ON A.aircraftType LIKE CONCAT('%', F.aircraftType, '%')' at line 1

Comment: Fixed, I forgot the FROM keyword

Comment: Yes-yes, I noticed this.Thanks a lot.